# Podio App Create not respecting Field external_id

Tags: api, podio

I'm running into an issue with the Podio App Create API call:
https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/add-new-app-22351

It does not appear to respect external_id for fields.

For example, given:

```
... 
[fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => text
                    [external_id] => title
                    [config] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Name
...
```

The resulting field will have an external id of "name" and not "title".

This is a rather big issue as when trying to make exact copies of apps (into places that clone won't go), the change in field ids causes GF flows to break.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Per the API documentation there is no "external_id" input in this call. The external IDs are always a standardized version of the field label though. (e.g. if you have 2 Name fields the first will be "name" and the second will be "name-2").

Alternatively, you could just run "get app" https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349 to see what the external IDs ended up being.